# ImportError: No module named diversely.settings.dev

Tags: python, django, django-settings

I've just completed a django tutorial, and after creating a settings folder and reconfiguring my database in my base.py, my website isn't loading, and I'm getting an ImportError. Any thoughts?

Here's the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/m.zayas/Desktop/env1/bin/django-admin", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute_from_command_line())
  File "/Users/m.zayas/Desktop/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/m.zayas/Desktop/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 316, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/Users/m.zayas/Desktop/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Users/m.zayas/Desktop/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/Users/m.zayas/Desktop/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 97, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named diversely.settings.dev
```

Here is my base.py:

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '_h0tyj2^#5x2jh$9!&p0589-zop-0aiwok)x(sf+u-jjhw9l*o'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'accounts',
    'home',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'diversely.middleware.LoginRequiredMiddleware'
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'diversely.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'accounts/templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'diversely.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'diversely/media')


LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/home/'

LOGIN_URL = '/account/login'

LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS = (
    r'^account/logout/$',
    r'^account/register/$',
    r'^account/reset-password/$',
    r'^account/reset-password/done/$',
    r'^account/reset-password/$',
    r'^account/reset-password/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$',
    r'^account/reset-password/complete/$',

)

EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
EMAIL_PORT = 1025
```

my wsgi:

```
"""
WSGI config for diversely project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "diversely.settings.prod")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

dev.py:

```
from diversely.settings.base import *

# Override base.py settings here

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

try:
    from diversely.settings.local import *
except:
    pass
```

prod.py:

```
from diversely.settings.base import *

# Override base.py settings here
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


try:
    from diversely.settings.local import *
except:
    pass
```

folder structure:
here's my folder structure:

```
diversely
  Ldiversely
    L settings.py
      L __init__.py
      L base.py
      L dev.py
      L local.py
      L production.py
```

Comment: did you renamed your settings.py to base.py? and can you post the folder structure

Comment: Apparently, it's a `PYTHONPATH` problem. You need to add a folder containing `diversely.settings` package to `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: check your manage.py file

Comment: folder structure added to post

Comment: Add __init__.py file in each directory..

Answer (score -1):

Your folder structure should be like this,

```
- diversely
  --- __init__.py
  --- settings
      ---- __init__.py
      ---- base.py
      ---- dev.py
      ---- production.py
      ---- local.py
```

Each directory must contain an **__init__.py** file. If not Django raises "No module found" error.

Note: If your folder's name is "settings.py", then change it to "settings".